# Is it possible to turn on and off different notifications for different things in one app? (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, onesignal, android-push-notification

For notifications for Android/iOS is it possible to turn on and off different notifications for different things in one app?

For example, we send notifications to the user using OneSignal service.

The first one if the user has not visited the application for a long time and another notification when there is a promotion in the store. So we have two different notifications.

Is it possible for the user to be able to turn off one of these notifications (manually in the app settings) and the other to work, or we can only turn off notifications completely?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're called `Notification Channels` in Android. For every notification, you set a notification channel it belongs to. That way, the user can enable/disable specific channels.